# Map function nested within a Foreach is not behaving as Expected Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, underscore.js

Essentially I am attempting to loop through an array of roles and compare it's related permissions with the master list array and set boolean values within this loop. So I want to alter the original array I'm looping over, adding in the values from the master list that don't exist, and setting a true key value pair for the original values, and a false key value pair for the added values. I can console log out all of the data in the loop and the code I've written seems to do as I'm expecting until I log out the final result wherein both nested arrays contain the booleans from the last time around the loop. There must be some gap in my understanding of map. I also feel like there has to be a much simpler way of doing this without nesting (which I'm trying to learn how to avoid or refactor).

Example Code:

```
 let roles = [];
    let allPerms = [];
    roles.push({
     name: 'role 1',
     label: 'role-label-1',
 permissions: [
    {
    name: 'permission 1',
    label: 'permission-1'
  },
  {
    name: 'permission 2',
    label: 'permission-2'
  }]
},
{
 name: 'role 2',
 label: 'role-label-2',
 permissions: [
    {
    name: 'permission 3',
    label: 'permission-3'
  },
  {
    name: 'permission 4',
    label: 'permission-4'
  }]
});

allPerms.push({
    name: 'permission 1',
    label: 'permission-1'
  },
  {
    name: 'permission 2',
    label: 'permission-2'
  },
  {
    name: 'permission 3',
    label: 'permission-3'
  },
  {
    name: 'permission 4',
    label: 'permission-4'
  });

console.log(roles);
console.log(allPerms);

function setRoles() {
  roles.forEach(function (val, key, array) {
      let selected = _.difference(array[key].permissions, allPerms);
      let mappedPerms = allPerms.map( function(v, k) {
          let name = _.find(selected, function(i) {
              return i.name == v.name;
          });
          if (typeof name != "undefined" && name.name == v.name) {
              v.selected = true;
          } else if (typeof name == "undefined"){
              v.selected = false;
          }
          return v;
      });
      console.log('ROLE '+key);
      console.log(mappedPerms[0].selected);
      console.log(mappedPerms[0].name);
      console.log(mappedPerms[1].selected);
      console.log(mappedPerms[1].name);
      console.log(mappedPerms[2].selected);
      console.log(mappedPerms[2].name);
      console.log(mappedPerms[3].selected);
      console.log(mappedPerms[3].name);
      array[key].permissions = mappedPerms
  });
  return roles;
}

let testRoles = setRoles();
console.log(testRoles);
```

Here is a jSFiddle working example of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/patrickisgreat/fu3hza1w/1/

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "role 1",
    "label": "role-label-1",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "name": "permission 1",
        "label": "permission-1",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "name": "permission 2",
        "label": "permission-2",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "name": "permission 3",
        "label": "permission-3",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "name": "permission 4",
        "label": "permission-4",
        "selected": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "role 2",
    "label": "role-label-2",
    "permissions": [
      {
        "name": "permission 1",
        "label": "permission-1",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "name": "permission 2",
        "label": "permission-2",
        "selected": false
      },
      {
        "name": "permission 3",
        "label": "permission-3",
        "selected": true
      },
      {
        "name": "permission 4",
        "label": "permission-4",
        "selected": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your `.map()` call always returns the element from `allPerms` - it does not create new elements.

Comment: Hi, that's what I want it to do -- but for each role I want it to set that boolean based on the difference between allPerms and selected.... and each time around the loop the console.log displays the correct booleans for each role -- yet at the end of the loop both role's booleans match. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you add an example of your expected output?

Comment: @funkenstein the point is that `allPerms` contains the objects it contains. The code in your `.map()` callback modifies the object, but the next call to `.map()` will modify the exact same object again. Returning a reference to an object does not make a copy. You're using the same set of objects over and over again, in other words, and only the last-made changes will be there when everything finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.some` could be useful for you here. `forEach` role we map over `allPerms` and rebuild the role's permissions. `role.permissions.some` can be used to check for the pre-existence of a given permission on the role.

```
function setRoles() {

  roles.forEach(function (role) {

    role.permissions = allPerms.map(function (perm) {

      return {
        name: perm.name,
        label: perm.label,
        selected: role.permissions.some(function (rolePerm) {
          return rolePerm.name === perm.name
        })
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly! Thank You! but.... can you explain to me why my original code didn't work? I'm trying to learn and get better at refactoring.

Comment: As @Pointy pointed out, you were mutating the permission objects within `allPerms`. Objects in JavaScript are passed by reference, meaning that if you make a change to them (like set a `selected` property). Everywhere that object is passed (or in your case, pushed into an array), these are just pointers to the EXACT same object. Further mutations are visible everywhere else the object is referenced. But in my answer we are creating brand new permission objects with the desired `selected`.  [Here is an article on it](http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/understand-value-and-reference-types-in-javascript/)